# Error deploying a public source code to my dev org

Tags: apex, deployment, ant

I am trying to deploy the source code from this website - `http://advancedapex.com/samplecode/` . For Third edition book `version 1.0.` I downloaded the zip file and extracted it. I got the Src file which I placed in the force.com ant migration tool folder. Path `salesforceAnt/Sample/RetrieveUnpackaged/src`. The same folder has package.xml. All these files can be found at the link I provided.

I assumed that to push the src code to my dev org all I need to do is place these files at the right place i.e. s`alesforceAnt/Sample/RetrieveUnpackaged/src` and run `ant deployUnpackaged` command. But I get an error that deployment failed:

All the components failed except the custom object(It has *). Below is a generic error I get:

```
package.xml (AppConfigSupport) -- Error: An object 'AppConfigSupport' of type ApexClass was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
```

All the `apex class, trigger, validation rule etc` whatever present in package.xml failed with the above error( substitute the name and type of the component)

I was unable to deploy. Any idea why this error came up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default values for deploy is to assume that there is a single package (`singlePackage="true"`). In other words, your file structure should look *exactly* as follows:

```
└───retrieveUnpackaged
    │ package.xml
    ├───classes/*
    ├───objects/*
    ├───staticresources/*
    └───triggers/*
```

However, if you placed it in `src`, that means your file system probably looks like:

```
└───retrieveUnpackaged
    │ package.xml
    └───src
        ├───classes/*
        ├───objects/*
        ├───staticresources/*
        └───triggers/*
```

This will not work. `package.xml` must be in the same folder as `classes`, `objects`, and other folders.

If you want to keep `src`, you can, but make sure that `package.xml` is in the correct location:

```
└───retrieveUnpackaged
    └───src
        │ package.xml
        ├───classes/*
        ├───objects/*
        ├───staticresources/*
        └───triggers/*
```

Also, in order to support this type of deployment, you must *also* specify `singlePackage="false"`, which tells the system that there is a further level of folders that describe (potentially) multiple packages.

---

All this said, I would say that you're probably wasting your time. Take the original zip file unmodified from the web site, go to https://workbench.developerforce.com/, Login using OAuth to your org (Sandbox, Developer, and Production orgs are supported), go to Metadata > Deploy, upload the zip file using the Single Package option checked, and you're done.

The Metadata Toolkit, while it was a novel idea for its time, has been superseded by more powerful tools. You should ideally look into DX, Force.com IDE, MavensMate, IntelliJ, Workbench, or any of a number of other tools that are far more powerful and are easier to use.

Comment: Hi, I got the zip file from the website. Did not modify it and used workbench. I get an error - problem: No package.xml found . Wondering if the structure should be changed inside the zip file?